# On-the-fly minifying css and js

Tags: javascript, css, build-automation, daemon, minify

What tools can minify JS/CSS files after saving files without using console? I want something like [SimpLESS](http://wearekiss.com/simpless). Write and update some js and css files and they minify and concatenate in two "build" files like that daemon program do automatically with LESS.

Comment: Are you editing and saving online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CodeKit](http://incident57.com/codekit/) for Mac.

Comment: Does alternative exist for Windows?

Comment: Not that I know of. Is there any reason why you're afraid of the command line?

Comment: Laziness is the root of all evil :)

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/hkasera/minify) out. I have written a python script that does it on the fly if you add it as a git hook in case you are using git for versioning. If not then also the script may help you out.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows: [Smalify](http://smalify.net/) works for me, if I'm not using CoffeeScript.  I haven't tried them, but there are several other CodeKit alternatives [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/codekit/?platform=windows).

You can always find a plugin for your Text Editor.  I don't know which editor you are using, but most of the popular ones either have build systems, have strong plugin communities, or both.

- Sublime Text 2: Tons of plugins, and you can customize a build and save script.
- Notepad++: Vibrant community, has minification plugins that would work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Check this python script.

http://github.com/hkasera/minify

It minifies js as well as css files too. It stores detailed log files and you can add this script as a git hook and save yourself from doing it manually everytime.

Hope it may help!